# One entity type multiple database contexts?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

**Context Inheritance**

```
// MobileContext has VisitPlan, Customer, etc. that all the following contexts need.
public MobileContext : DbContext { } 
public AuthenticationEntities : MobileContext { }
public OrderEntities : MobileContext { }
public ThriftEntities : MobileContext { }
```

The contexts are code-first and I do not use them to create the database.

**Description**

I create an instance of `UserPermissionService` which has repositories for `VisitPlan`, `UserBranch`, etc. All of the repositories are in the `AuthenticationEntities` with `Customer` and `VisitPlan` being a part of `MobileContext` which `AuthenticationEntites` and all other contexts inherit from.

**Problem**

When I try to execute a query that joins `UserBranch` and `VisitPlan` it tells me I cannot query between two contexts, but if I look in the debugger at the `DbContext` of the repositories they are both of type `AuthenticationEntities`.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

---

**The Query**

```
//
// USER-BRANCHES: Check the user branches table for permissions.
//
var branches = Branches
    .GetAll()
    .Where(x => x.AzureUser.Username == username && x.StartDate <= effective && x.EndDate >= effective);

//
// USER-ROUTES: Check the user routes table for permissions.
//
var routes = Routes
    .GetAll()
    .Where(x => x.AzureUser.Username == username && x.StartDate <= effective && x.EndDate >= effective);

//
// USER-DRIVERS: Check the user driver number table for permissions.
//
var drivers = DriverNumbers
    .GetAll()
    .Where(x => x.AzureUser.Username == username && x.StartDate <= effective && x.EndDate >= effective);

//
// VISIT PLANS: Retrieve a list of visit plans currently active.
//
var vpQuery = VisitPlans
    .GetAll()
    .Where(
        x => x.FromDate <= effective && x.ToDate >= effective
          && (
                 branches.Any(b => b.Branch == x.Branch)
              || routes.Any(r => r.Route == x.Route)
              || drivers.Any(d => d.DriverNumber == x.DriverNumber)
          )
    );

//
// QUERY: Retrieve all the customers which have effective stop plans and are included in one of the above queries.
//
var customerQuery = vpQuery
    .Join(
        inner: Customers.GetAll(),
        outerKeySelector: x => x.SAPCustomerID,
        innerKeySelector: x => x.SAPCustomerID,
        resultSelector: (vp, c) => c
    );
```

Where:

- `VisitPlans` is of type `Repository<VisitPlan>` which is using `AuthenticationEntities` as its `DbContext`
- `Customers` is of type `Repository<Customer>` which is using `AuthenticationEntities` as its `DbContext`
- `Branches` is of type `Repository<UserBranch>` which is using `AuthenticationEntities` as its `DbContext`
- `Routes` is of type `Repository<UserRoute>` which is using `AuthenticationEntities` as its `DbContext`
- `DriverNumbers` is of type `Repository<UserDriverNumber>` which is using `AuthenticationEntities` as its `DbContext`

Comment: Please share your query code. You should have a single `DbContext` instance that is responsible for the query and all the entities that are returned from that query. You can't join across different `DbContext` instances (*also I am not sure why you would want to*).

Comment: If I add the query code it's going to require a bunch of other code and the page will be a mile long. The query isn't the problem, the problem is I have a handful of entities (i.e. VisitPlan, etc) in all contexts and when I join between those entities and entities of one specific context (e.g. UserBranch, UserRoute, etc) it complains about two contexts even though the repositories are using instances of `AuthenticationEntities`. So to me it seems like there is an issue with `VisitPlan` and other entities being on multiple contexts, and that is what I'm asking about.

Comment: @Shelby115 It sounds like you need to rethink your design.  You really should only have one context unless there are some special circumstances, such as having multiple databases.  If you're using a repository pattern, (which isn't really needed with Entity Framework), than you should be injecting the context whenever it's needed.

Comment: That does not make sense (*to me*). Please provide an [mcve], you do not have to provide your full actual production Linq/Lambda, just an [mcve] that illustrates why you are having issues.

Comment: I added the query, but what I have been trying to say is that they're all using the same `DbContext` which is `AuthenticationEntities` and as such the exception complaining about a query across to entities does not make sense unless the problem is inheritance, which is what I'm asking about. I want to be able to have this inheritance structure for multiple contexts on the same database so that my code-base isn't such a clutter.

Comment: You need to be using a SINGLE INSTANCE of your DbContext.  Post your repository code.  Are you injecting a context or are you creating one in each repository?  If it's the latter that's why you're having this issue.

Comment: Ah, shoot. I read 'Single Instance' as single context. My bad. It makes sense on why it is not working now, sorry about that.

Comment: See my first commend and the comment from `JNYRanger`. The key words here are *single instance*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter that they are of the same type.  You must be using a single instance of your `DbContext`.  A single query (`Join` in this case) must be done on that single context instance when using entity framework.

Ideally, you should only be using a single `DbContext` instance that's responsible for making all of the queries to the database.  The only reason you would have multiple instances (for a single request) would be if you are using multiple databases.

However, let's assume that you DO need to have multiple context objects.  What you would need to do is query each context and pull the results into memory.  This can be done by calling `.ToList()` at the end of each query.

Once the data is memory you can join them together.  Here's an example:

```
var vpQuery = authContext.VisitPlan.Where(x => x == something).ToList();
var ubQuery = permissionContext.UserBranch.Where(u => u == somethingElse).ToList();
var joined = vpQuery.Join(vpQuery, vp => vp.UserKey, ub => ub.UserKey, (vp, ub) => new { Property1 = ub.Something, Property2 = vp.SomethingElse);
```

However, based on what you posted, you definitely don't need multiple context instances.  Most likely your repository code, which is probably unnecessary, is holding or creating a context that is different from the other repositories's context object(s).  They should all be sharing a single context instance if you want to use lazy loading and actually generate & execute the query only when needed.